# CNN Model Training Problem (%16 Accuracy)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a homework about Neural Networks. I need to develop a flower recognition application.

First of all, i tried to learn how to classify cat-dog photos from [that link](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-convolutional-neural-network-to-classify-photos-of-dogs-and-cats/) and apply myself. After that, i started to adapt that model to flower recognition with 5 labels.

Although model runs properly, training isn't successful and accuracy is %16.

Here accuracy plot is.

[image: Classification Accuracy Plot]

```py
def define_model_one_block():
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', padding='same', input_shape=(200, 200, 3)))
 model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2)))
 model.add(Flatten())
 model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_uniform'))
 model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))
 opt = SGD(lr=0.001,momentum=0.9)
 model.compile(optimizer=opt,loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
 return model
```

```
def run_model_one_block():
    model = define_model_one_block()
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0/255.0)
    #prepare train and test iterators
    train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('flowers/train/',
                class_mode='binary',batch_size=64,target_size=(200,200))
    test_it = datagen.flow_from_directory('flowers/test/',
            class_mode='binary', batch_size=64, target_size=(200, 200))
    #fit model
    history = model.fit_generator(train_it,steps_per_epoch=len(train_it),
            validation_data=test_it,validation_steps=len(test_it),epochs=20,verbose=0)
    #evaluate model
    _, acc = model.evaluate_generator(test_it, steps=len(test_it), verbose=0)
    print('>%.3f' % (acc*100.0))
    #plot of learning curves
    summarize_diagnostics(history)
```

Comment: loss='binary_crossentropy' you are not having 2(binary) classes here. You are doing multi classification. You are using wrong loss function. and also the class_mode you have set as 'binary'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 5 classes. Therefore you are no longer doing binary classification. Here are the things you need to change

```
In train_it and test_it  change class_mode to 'categorical'
code model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')) should be changed to
model.add(Dense(5,activation='softmax'))
code  model.compile(optimizer=opt,loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
should be changed to
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Also I do not  think your model is sufficiently complex enough to achieve a high level of accuracy. Give it a try but if it does not do very well modify it as follows

```
IMG_HEIGHT=200
IMG_WIDTH=200
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH , 3)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH , 3)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH , 3)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(128, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH , 3)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Conv2D(256, 3, padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH , 3)),
    MaxPooling2D(),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(.3),
    Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(.3),
    Dense(5, activation='softmax')
])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It was one block VGG. I will try one block , two block and three block VGG models and compare the accuracy scores for homework.